# How do I revert an unfinished makemigration after adding a non-nullable field(Foreign) and filling it

Tags: django, django-migrations, revert

I made the mistake of adding a non-nullablle field and filling it with 1.

```
contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

(Contest is empty, new table)

```
 >>> python manage.py makemigrations contests
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'contest' to contestentry without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now
Type 'exit' to exit this prompt
>>> 1
```

When migrating it gave an error because the table of the model is empty.

```
>>> python manage.py migrate contests 
psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: insert or update on table "contests_contestentry" violates foreign key constraint "contests_contestentr_contest_id_7f53b874_fk_contests_"
DETAIL:  Key (contest_id)=(1) is not present in table "contests_contest".
```

I removed the field and tried to migrate back but it didn't work then I tried to revert the migrations but it gave the following error:

```
>>> python manage.py migrate contests 0007_remove_contestentry_nvotes

    Operations to perform:
      Target specific migration: 0007_remove_contestentry_nvotes, from contests
    Running migrations:
      No migrations to apply.
      Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
      Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

How do I revert back to migration_007 and then set the field to be able to be empty in the db?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by deleting the migrations in appname/migrations removing the conflicting code and running makemigrations migrate again

Answer (score 0):

You can revert by migrating to the previous migration.

For example, if your last two migrations are:

```
0010_previous_migration
0011_migration_to_revert

Then you would do:

./manage.py migrate my_app 0010_previous_migration
```

You can then delete migration 0011_migration_to_revert.

for an empty model:

```
contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=true)
```

Comment: I did this see OP I got the error: your models have changes that are not yet reflected

Comment: Okay, ia m sorry, have you tried to delete the corrupt object from your database by yourself?